# Преобразование класса родителя в класс потомок в C#

Tags: c#, типы

У меня есть два класса Polynom и PolynomSon (наследник Polynom). Класс Polynom содержит оператор суммы полиномов. Мне нужно написать оператор суммы для работы с наследником, который будет использовать оператор родителя, поэтому я пишу так:

```
 public static PolynomSon operator +(PolynomSon q, PolynomSon r)
 {
     Polynom t = new PolynomSon();
     t = (Polynom)q + r;
     return t as PolynomSon; //так дает null при преобразовании
 }
```

Не получается преобразовать из Polynom в PolynomSon после суммирования. Подскажите, пожалуйста, как исправить, чтобы получилось преобразовать?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Polynom t = new PolynomSon();
```

здесь вызов `new PolynomSon()` не имеет смысла, так как переменной `t` сразу же присваивается другое значение.

---

Невозможно "преобразовать" результат оператора `Polynom.+`

```
t = (Polynom)q + r;
```

в `PolynomSon`, потому что этот результат не является `PolynomSon`.

Вам придется написать реализацию сложения, где результатом является `PolynomSon`.

---

Или добавить в класс `PolynomSon` конструктор

```
public PolynomSon(Polynom p) { ... }
```

и делать:

```
return new PolynomSon((Polynom)q + r);
```